# How to login to my server's control panel

Tags: dedicated-server

i got a dedicated server in a hosting company and after they setup it, they sent to me like this configuration :

```
Main IP: xxx.xx.xx.xx

Access data:

Login: root
Password: XXXXXXXXXX

MySQL Login: root
MySQL Password: XXXXXXXXXXX
```

i try to access with the first details in FTP but i can't.

is there a software to access the server like CloudBerry S3 for dedicated servers  ?

Note: my control panel has only billing infos and only server bandwidth and traffic, nothing else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Linux server, you'd probably use a secure shell login via the Ip address that they provided  you. If you're using Windows, you can probably do a remote desktop session into the machine via the IP address also. You would use the login and password provided either way to gain access to the machine.

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it **comes** with a control panel? It looks like they intend for you to log in via SSH on the command line. For FTP, you likely need to use SFTP instead of regular, insecure FTP.

On Windows, the Putty app will allow you to SSH. If your FTP client doesn't support SFTP, Mozilla's Filezilla will.

On Mac and Linux, SSH is built in.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you contact your hosting co.